# Asset Pipeline Compression Fingerprint Position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have a weird problem...

I precompile assets successfully by

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Then when I run my application on production some assets are served successfully and others fail.

I tried to find why some fail. I found those are failing who have . (dot) in their name

Example:

```
http://localhost:3001/assets/jquery-1.7.1.min-92db3e9645bf381db699af5c85229722.js
```

No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery-1.7.1.min-92db3e9645bf381db699af5c85229722.js"

**However**, when I try to change the **fingerprint position** to be before the first **dot** and open it from browser, it works

```
http://localhost:3001/assets/jquery-1-92db3e9645bf381db699af5c85229722.7.1.min.js
```

So,

```
http://localhost:3001/assets/jquery-1.7.1.min-92db3e9645bf381db699af5c85229722.js fails
http://localhost:3001/assets/jquery-1-92db3e9645bf381db699af5c85229722.7.1.min.js works
```

Any reasons?